# GWT: how to use default (standard) styles + user supplied styles?

Tags: css, gwt

I have some combobox that is defaulted to `gwt-ListBox` style. I need to use this style plus my own style that I wrote in `module_name.css` when I use `cmbobox1.setStyleName("user-defined-style");`

I find that the style `gwt-ListBox` is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
void addStyleName(java.lang.String style)
```

Adds a secondary or dependent style name to this object.

Answer (score 0):

With complex widgets (those who have dependant styles) like DialogBox you should use:

`void setStylePrimaryName(java.lang.String style)`

to set base style and update all dependant styles.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "`setStyleName`" you are *replacing all styles* of element. When you use "`addStyleName`" you're *adding styles to existing* styles.